# if else in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary with enumerate as key and `1` as value if the value in a list is an integer and `'1'` if not.

I cant figure out why this is giving syntax error on second line?

```
a = [9, 8, 7, 'a', 'b', 'c']
d = {e:1 if isinstance(b, int) else e:'1' for e,b in enumerate(a)}
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I want:

```
d = {0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:'1', 4:'1', 5:'1'}
```

Comment: Because you've repeated `e:`; you can't do that, your conditional expression is just for the *value*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if/else` ternaries applies to a given **value**. In that case, that is the expression `1` or `'1'` not `e:1` or `e:'1'`.

```
d = {e:1 if isinstance(b, int) else '1' for e,b in enumerate(a)}
```

Comment: For clarity, the syntax is `{<exp>: <exp> for .. in ..}`; you can't make the `:` part of an expression.